# WCF PrincipalPermission with roles, configuring for sub-methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I want to keep this as simple as possible, so I'm not posting any code,as it will probably just confuse things.

I have implemented security in my application using WCF's role based authorisation.

Assume that I have 4 methods on my publicly exposed interface

- GetPerson
- DeletePerson
- UpdatePerson
- GetSurnameAndForename

I have attached the

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="POWERUSER")]
```

to the first 3, and the

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="GENERALUSER")]
```

to the final one.

This works fine, and prevents a 'GENERALUSER' from accessing the first 3 methods.

However the method GetSurnameAndForename internally calls the GetPerson method, which fails. I understand why it fails, but is there a preferred way to allow GetSurnameAndForename to call GetPerson withouth having the POWERUSER role ?

The only way I can think of doing this, is adding an extra check in the IsInRole method to check the CallStack to see if this call has come from an internal method, or an external call. This solution works, but it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is very easy solution. Wrap the logic offered by `GetPerson` to private method and call that new method from both `GetPerson` and `GetSurnameAndForename`.

Comment: thanks, that's very obvious now that you say it. It's been rattling around inside my brain today, sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.. thanks again !!

Answer (score 2):

Crisscrossing boundaries secured with Principal Permission Attributes is a recipe for disaster.